# most STLish way to init array with boost intrusive pointers

Tags: c++, boost, stl, scoped-ptr

I have this:

```
struct Node;
typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<Node> NodeSPtr;

...

boost::scoped_array<NodeSPtr> nodes(new NodeSPtr[size]);

...

// "pollute" operations ...

...

// reset all the items in the array
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    nodes[i].reset();
```

What is the cleanest more STLish way to initialize the array. Note that the code is performance sensitive and using vector is not an option.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want. It seems like you just want to reset the `scoped_array`. There is a [Reset()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) function in `boost::scoped_array`.

Comment: scoped_array reset frees all the items in the array it does not reset them

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor of `intrusive_ptr` has a postcondition that get() == 0 according to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#constructors). So to default-construct the array values, just stick a pair of curly braces (uniform initialization) after the `new`, like so:

```
boost::scoped_array<NodeSPtr> nodes(new NodeSPtr[size]{});
```

You can also use parentheses if you cannot use the uniform initialization syntax.

Comment: the initial initialization is OK. The question is hoe to reset the array to NULL pointers at some other point

Comment: I see, I don't think there's really a good way to do that other than a `for` loop like you already said. Could also try a `std::fill_n` or something if you want it to look a bit nicer.